# If f(n)∈Ω(n) how do I prove or disprove f(n)∈O(n)

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics

If f(n)∈Ω(n) how do I prove f(n)∈O(n)

I feel it is true, but not sure how to show it

the way I see it c1*n =< f(n) =< c2*n holds, but so confused on how to show it

Comment: $n^2 \in \Omega(n)$ but $n^2 \not\in O(n)$...!

Comment: but I'm trying to show it for n not n^2

Comment: Here I take $f(n) = n^2$.

Comment: It might help to actually state what how you have defined $f(n)$.

Comment: It's a tutorial question and f(n) is not defined, literally just says If f(n) is Ω(n) prove or disprove f(n) is O(n)

Comment: From nik's comment above, you have a counterexample.

Comment: Ok so I set f(n) = n^2

Answer (score 2):

$$\Omega(n)\not\subset O(n)\qquad O(n)\not\subset\Omega(n)\qquad\Omega(n)\cap O(n)=\Theta(n)$$